# Websupport shell stop when I close shell card

Tags: shell, server, bots, discord

I'm host on websupport. I have domain but there is also free version of shell server. I know that after hour it stop automatically. But when I close shell card it get stopped even thought. Can anybody help me? I want to get discord bot running when I have turned off my pc at least 1 hour.

Comment: You could try starting a tmux server then detaching the session.  That should keep the process running even though your shell process ends.  It's possible that they've set up their service to prevent this, where your processes only run while you are logged in.  In that case, I doubt there's a way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanx, can you please send me URL of some YouTube tutorial?